# PHP Image upload on info edit

Tags: php, image, forms, upload

I have a form that allows me to edit data in my database. I need to
upload the image to a folder once the form is submitted. This is an edit page and I the way I have it set up is the image name is called from the database and the image is stored in the folder. Can anyone help me?

```
<?php 
 // if there are any errors, display them
 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 ?> 

 <form action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
 <div>
 <p><strong>ID:</strong> <?php echo $id; ?></p>
 <label> Job Name:</label><br><br>
 <input type="text" name="job_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/><br/>
 <label></label><br><br>
 <label>Job Thumbnail:</label><br><br>
 <input id="upload"  name="file" type="file" size="10"><br><br>
 <input id="filename" type="text" name="job_timg" placeholder="This Fills Automatcially" value="<?php echo $timg; ?>"/><br/>
 <label> Job Name:</label><br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </div>
 </form> 
 </body>
 </html> 
 <?php
 }

// connect to the database
 include('connect.php');

 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 // $_FILES["file"]["error"] is HTTP File Upload variables $_FILES["file"] "file" is the name of input field you have in form tag.

 // confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
 if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
 {
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['job_name']));
 $timg = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['job_timg']));

 // check that name/image fields are both filled in
 if ($name == '' || $timg == '')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 //error, display form
 renderForm($id, $name, $timg, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_job SET job_name='$name', job_timg='$timg' WHERE job_id='$id'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 


 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: gallery_edit.php"); 
 }
 }
 else
 {
 // if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }


 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
 {

 // get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
 {
 // query db
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_job WHERE job_id=$id")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 // check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
 if($row)
 {

 // get data from db
 $name = $row['job_name'];
 $timg = $row['job_timg'];

 // show form
 renderForm($id, $name, $timg, '');
 }
 else
 // if no match, display result
 {
 echo "No results!";
 }
 }
 else
 // if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error
 {
 echo 'Error!';
 }


 }






?>
```

Comment: dealing with files requires using a valid enctype inside your form tags

Comment: You're welcome Connor. I decided to post an answer below where you can accept it in order to close the question. That way, it will also tell others that a solution was found.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with files, the form must include a valid enctype.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

For more information on dealing with files, visit the following page on PHP.net:

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php